# .NET Delegate passed as parameter issue

Tags: c#, delegates

Confused by C# delegate passing as parameter:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        Action holder = delegate{};
        //a.Attach1(holder); //nothing printed
        a.Attach2(ref holder);//print as expected

        holder();
    }
}

public class A
{
    private void P1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inaccessible");
    }
    public void P2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accessible");
    }
    public void Attach1(Action holder)
    {
        holder += P1;
        holder += P2;
    }
    public void Attach2(ref Action holder)
    {
        holder += P1;
        holder += P2;
    }
}
```

delegate is reference type, why does it still need to be passed with ref in font to work correctly as in Attach2, something like value type?

From C++ experience, delegate is just a function pointer,  Attach1(Action holder) is something like  Attach1(Action* holder), the origial holder is passed as 'value', thus not assigned, while in the second case, Attach2(ref Action holder) is something like  Attach1(Action** holder), the pointer is actually passed, thus can be manipulated correctly. But why in .NET there is no indication or hint???

Comment: If you're thinking of delegate as "just a function pointer", what (in your mental model) does `+=` do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because a delegate instance is **immutable**, and `+=` is a new assignment to a **new** delegate instance; it is basically:

```
holder = (Action)Delegate.Combine(holder, P1);
holder = (Action)Delegate.Combine(holder, P2);
```

If you don't pass that as `ref`, the new value will not be seen outside the method.

Or to put that in simpler terms - consider a `string`; a `string` is likewise immutable and `+=` is an assignment. Now consider:

```
public void Append(string s) {
    s += "[suffix]";
}
public void Append2(ref string s) {
    s += "[suffix]";
}
```

If we call:

```
string x = "abc";
Append(x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

we will see `abc`. If we call

```
string x = "abc";
Append2(ref x);
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

we will see `abc[suffix]` - *for the exact same reasons*.

Comment: for those of us who haven't used the word immutable since university http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object :)

Answer (score 2):

```
holder += P1;
```

This line effectively creates a *new* delegate and assigns it to the `holder` variable. It doesn't modify the existing delegate.

So:

```
Action holder = delegate{};
a.Attach2(ref holder);

holder(); //<-- holder is no longer the delegate assigned two lines above
```

And of course, you need to use `ref` to make this work, since otherwise the assignment inside `Attach2` only affects what is effectively a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

As stated on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx)

> Do not confuse the concept of passing by reference with the concept of
>   reference types. The two concepts are not the same. A method parameter
>   can be modified by ref regardless of whether it is a value type or a
>   reference type. There is no boxing of a value type when it is passed
>   by reference.

See the second example on that link, it explains the question

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are just experimenting with this. You would normally send the function in that you wanted to be added to a member delegate, and then the member would be the new object return by +=

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        a.Attach();
        a.doSomething();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public delegate void handler();
    public handler doSomething;
    private void P1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Inaccessible");
    }
    public void P2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Accessible");
    }
    public void Attach()
    {
        doSomething += P1;
        doSomething += P2;
    }
}
```